# how to get around Field XPath keeps changing when trying to scrape orbitz.com with Selenium & Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Below is my script using which I am trying to scrape Orbitz.com. The problem is that the XPath for the SAME field (let's take the FROM Airport field) keeps changing. One time it is `fromDate_XPath = ".//*[@id='8f57e1cb92a99815ca1085ac0f6d31db']"` and the next time it is `.//*[@id='0a3807a6e50ffd4cc05eaca5b6aada17']`.

Is orbitz specifically doing this to prevent scraping?
I would have thought if I used their website to get links to buy tickets they would gain and hence would allow me to scrape, no?

Is there any way around this problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.orbitz.com/")
# X-PATHS FOR DIFFERENT FIELDS
fltOption_Xpath = ".//*[@id='products']/div/fieldset/div[2]/label[1]/div"
fromAir_XPath = ".//*[@id='2de60aafe0629114603daf0bc1ab52a6']"
toAir_XPath = ".//*[@id='9c64cbe5f29f6f28b64ddb9811e102b5']"
fromDate_XPath = ".//*[@id='8f57e1cb92a99815ca1085ac0f6d31db']"

toDate_XPath = ".//*[@id='aa8496535efd1aec3badf9423813fbbd']"


selFlightsOption_Element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(fltOption_Xpath))

selFlightsOption_Element.click()


fromAir_Element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(fromAir_XPath))
toAir_ELement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(toAir_XPath))
fromDate_Element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(fromDate_XPath))
toDate_Element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(toDate_XPath))



fromAir_Element.click()
fromAir_Element.clear()
fromAir_Element.send_keys("IAH")

toAir_Element.click()
toAir_Element.clear()
toAir_Element.send_keys("MUM")
```

Comment: You should read the terms and conditions for orbitz... my guess is that they don't allow scraping of their site.

Comment: @JeffC - Is using `Selenium` considered the same as `scraping`? Selenium is actually launching the browser and navigating like a human would. I only plan to do this few times a day. Trying to understand if this can be against their TOC.

Comment: Scraping is using any automated tool to take information from their pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `id` attributes of the inputs are dynamically generated, don't rely your locators on them.

You can switch to `name`s - from what I see they don't change and are quite readable. For instance, for the "From date" input in a "Hotel Only" mode:

```
fromDate_Element = driver.find_element_by_name("hotel.chkin")
```

or if you need an XPath for some reason:

```
fromDate_Element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='hotel.chkin']")
```

Comment: Thanks that helps. I dont know why I thought XPath would be more accurate always. Is going by name usually the first way to scrape? (new to scraping)

Comment: @user1406716 I would not say yes, but `id`s and `name`s are usually the first candidates if they are available and look reliable..Btw and just FYI, another option here would be to use the labels to locate the corresponding inputs. For instance,  find the `Check-in` label element and get the corresponding input. There is a huge number of location strategies..glad to help.